# Can any advise us how to optimize the SendAndWaitForResponse(Byte[], Int32, Int32, String) method?

Tags: vb.net, printing, zebra-printers, zpl, zpl-ii

We are finding that setting the printer response time and initial timeout
is causing operations to be very slow. With the below code -

```
thePrinterConn.SendAndWaitForResponse(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(zplData),
960,650, "null")
^XA
^RFW,H^FD30361F8A7803428000000001^FS^FN1
^RFR,H^FS^HV1^FS
^XZ
```

We need to ensure that we first encode each tag & then read the data on
each tag, but with the send and wait for response command, and the values
960 and 650 - the process is very slow. However when we decrease the
values, then the printer ends up skipping tags & we do not have control on
the tags.
We are using the UsbConnection Class - not the driver printer class.

Can you advise us how to optimize the `SendAndWaitForResponse(Byte[], Int32, Int32, String)` method?

Or an alternative and faster way to send commands and get a response from the printer?

Comment: You missed to specify the language you are using. Please add a corresponding tag to your question.

Comment: im using vb.net -win forms

Comment: The request was to edit your post in order to add the appropriate tag (done now).

Comment: - we have implemented the clear buffer, and our responses are coming properly in line
- however our speed is still quite slow in comparison to bartender, is there any other method for us to optimize this? we are only encoding 96 bits of data

- it takes about 1.4 seconds per tag, with bartender it takes less than a second per tag
is there any other method for us to optimize this?